# Get min value of a rule in Prolog

Tags: prolog, knights-tour

I'm trying to solve Knight Tour problem. I need to get the position that has the minimum amount of movements. I have my rule that calculates the number of moves in a position (search_path), but I need to get the min of that rule (search_path_min).

```
    moves(X, Y, Xi, Yi, Size) :-
    ( Xi is X - 1, Yi is Y - 2 
    ; Xi is X - 1, Yi is Y + 2 
    ; Xi is X + 1, Yi is Y - 2
    ; Xi is X + 1, Yi is Y + 2
    ; Xi is X - 2, Yi is Y - 1 
    ; Xi is X - 2, Yi is Y + 1 
    ; Xi is X + 2, Yi is Y - 1
    ; Xi is X + 2, Yi is Y + 1 ),
    Xi > 0,
    Yi > 0,
    Xi =< Size*Size,
    Yi =< Size*Size.

posibles_moves(Size, X, Y, Tour, Xi, Yi):-
    moves(X, Y, Xi, Yi, Size),
    \+ member((Xi,Yi),Tour).

posibles_moves_count(Size, X, Y, Tour, Count):-
    findall(_, posibles_moves(Size, X, Y, Tour, Xi, Yi), Moves),
    length(Moves, Count).

search_path(Size, X, Y, Tour, Xi, Yi, Count):-
    posibles_moves(Size, X, Y, Tour, Xi, Yi),
    posibles_moves_count(Size, Xi, Yi, [(Xi,Yi)|Tour],Count).

search_path_min(Size, X, Y, Tour, Xi, Yi):-
    search_path(Size, X, Y, Tour, Xi, Yi, Count),
    ?
    ?
    ?
    ?

knight_tour(Size, X, Y, Tour, Path) :-
    length(Tour, L),
    L =:= Size * Size - 1,
    _Tour = [(X, Y) | Tour],
    reverse(_Tour, Path).

knight_tour(Size, X, Y, Tour, Path) :-
    length(Visits, L),
    L < Size * Size - 1,
    search_path_min(Size, X, Y, Tour, Xi, Yi),
    _Tour = [(X, Y) | Tour],
    knight_tour(Size, Xi, Yi, _Tour, Path).
```

My rule search_path I need to get the result that has the minimum value for the Count variable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it

```
search_path_min(Size, X, Y, Tour, Minimum):-
    findall(min(Xi,Yi,Count),search_path(Size,X,Y,Tour,Xi,Yi,Count),[H|Rest]),
    search_path_min(H,Rest,Minimum).

search_path_min(Minimum, [], Minimum).

search_path_min(min(X,Y,C),[min(X2,Y2,C2)|Rest],Minimum):-
    C < C2 -> search_path_min(min(X,Y,C),Rest,Minimum);
              search_path_min(min(X2,Y2,C2),Rest,Minimum).
```